# Power BI Stacked Area Chart not summing to 100%

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a stack area graph as seen in Image #1. I have chosen "Show value as > Percent of grand total", but it is not summing to 100%. If I choose a single date it does, so it is showing each month as a percent of all time and not for just that month.

What am I doing wrong?

Image 1:
[image]

The graph is suppose to show a percent of grant total per month, per each category. Image #2 shows my data, Image #3 shows what I am trying to achieve.

Image 2:
[image]

Image 3:
[image]